# JQuery Scroll functions are not working

Tags: jquery, scroll, bind

I'd just started to make a sliding menu with jquery, but no one scroll function works. JQuery is connected (I checked). I tried to play with console in Chrome and what I got is

```
> $("body").scrollTop();
  0
> $(window).scrollTop();
  0
```

That's fun, that the returning values of these functions are always equal to zero! 
Or for example I tried to use the scroll() function to bind the page scroll... It not works.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  alert('Its scrolling!');
});
```

or this code

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
  alert('And its scrolling TOO!');
});
```

No one works. What's problem in?
Any errors are not logging in console also.

My site is [http://q-2.su](http://q-2.su/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this in your page (the url you provided):

```
$(document).ready( function (){
    console.log('ready');
    $('.wrapper').scroll( function (){
    //-^------------------------------------here you are refering to the class but in
        console.log('scroll'); // ----------you used id
    });
});
```

so this would be:

```
$(document).ready( function (){
    console.log('ready');
    $('#wrapper').scroll( function (){
    //-^------------------------------------here you have to use # for id
        console.log('scroll'); 
    });
});
```